# ¿Existe "Petricor"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, vocabulario-técnico, palabras-raras

Anda circulando por el facebook una imagen que parece ser publicidad de Larousse.
[image]

En ella se menciona la palabra Petricor como el olor de la lluvia.

Como siempre desconfío de facebook así diga que viene de Larousse, verifiqué en la RAE y la palabra no se encuentra aunque si hay otras fuentes como wikipedia que la contienen. Pero igualmente un artículo en wikipedia es creado por cualquiera por lo que no es una fuente "oficial".

Al buscar encontré que en inglés hay un caso similar. La palabra *petrichor* esta recogida en wikipedia y en google_translate como:

> a pleasant smell that frequently accompanies the first rain after a long period of warm, dry weather.

Sin embargo al buscarla en mi diccionario favorito [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/petrichor) tampoco aparece.

¿Alguien puede confirmar la validez de la palabra **petricor**?

Comment: Ya puestos, "óbelo" no tiene en el DLE el significado que dice, "aspa" es un signo en forma de X en general, pero no especifica que sea el de la multiplicación, y "dysania" no viene. "Giste" es la única que acierta.

Comment: Recuerdo que cuando niño en la escuela el profesor nos dijo que no confiaramos en los diccionarios _Larousse_, porque son adaptaciones (o traducciones tal vez) del diccionario original que está en francés. Pensándolo ahora, me parece que no estaba muy en lo cierto, y de hecho recuerdo con harto cariño el _Pequeño Larousse Ilustrado_, que fue mi Wikipedia. Tal vez dé para pregunta: ¿alguien sabe si podemos confiar en los diccionarios Larousse, que fueron tan importantes en el pasado (al menos en Latinoamérica)?

Comment: Hay alguna historia de *petricor* (del inglés, del griego) [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petricor).

Comment: @Charlie también vi lo mismo que tu sobre óbelo y dysania pero pregunté por petricor porque es un olor que me gusta y me trae recuerdos. Además con óbelo en el facebook los han criticado bastante por haber hablado de división y dibujar el signo de radicación. Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra *petricor* parece ser un neologismo. Según la propia Wikipedia:

> El término petricor, *petrichor* en inglés, fue creado en 1964 por dos geólogos australianos, Isabel Joy Bear y R. G. Thomas. Apareció por primera vez en la revista Nature (993/2).

No he encontrado el término en casi ningún diccionario de ningún idioma cercano, [salvo en uno](http://wordinfo.info/searches/results/petrichor):

> **petrichor** (s) (noun), **petrichors** (pl)
>   1. The scent that comes up from a pavement, or dry earth, after rain has started to fall: The pleasant odor of *petrichor* often results after a long period of warm, dry weather.
>   It is believed that the oils from the rocks come from vegetation during dry periods and so the *petrichors* are adsorbed on the surfaces of stones and soil particles which are then spread into the air by the next rain.
>   2. Etymology: from Greek *petro*," stone, rocks" + *ichor*, "fluid that flows like blood in the veins of the gods."

Dado que parece ser un término usado en ámbitos científicos, preguntémosle a [Google Académico](https://scholar.google.es/). La búsqueda de *[petrichor](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=petrichor&btnG=)* arroja 268 resultados. Entre ellos están los artículos que dieron origen al término:

- *Petrichor and plant growth* (1965)
- *Genesis of petrichor* (1966)

Y otros más recientes que también lo usan:

- *Pondering petrichor: The smell of rain: How CSIRO invented a new word* (2015)

No tengo acceso al texto completo del artículo, pero su *abstract* dice así:

> Are you one of those people who can smell when the rain is coming? Ever wondered then what you're actually smelling?

Otros artículos usan la palabra en el texto, citando el artículo original de 1965 para explicar que el término es de invención reciente. Si buscamos *[petricor](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=petricor&btnG=)* aparecen 39 resultados, aunque muy pocos hacen referencia al término que nos ocupa. Uno de ellos (*[Hueles a pura tierra mojada](https://maestradelia.wordpress.com/category/ciencias-naturales/)*) dice:

> El distintivo aroma se conoce actualmente como *petricor*, palabra inventada en inglés —*petrichor*— por dos científicos australianos que allá por 1964 empezaron a estudiar en serio el fenómeno.

Así pues, yo diría que la palabra es un neologismo de reciente cuño, pero que ya está extendida y validada al menos en el ámbito científico. Dado que es una palabra que poca gente conoce y tiene poco uso fuera de este ámbito, es normal que la RAE no la haya recogido en el DLE. Pero yo diría, visto lo visto, que su validez está confirmada.

Comment: No sabía que existía Google Académico O_O. ¿De dónde sacas estas cosas? Te conoces todos los recursos

Comment: @blonfu es lo que pasa cuando empiezas a preocuparte por [publicar papers científicos](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-26869-9_4), que comienzas a tirar de buscadores especializados y acabas dando con ese recurso.

Answer (score 2):

Acá la [aclaración de la RAE en twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/866977571748986880?lang=es&fbclid=IwAR1uebfchi3qK7fH_1Tu0T523u3LPjq5ozlH8SeB46gkt4P4nLElIej2YdQ)

> Petricor es el nombre que recibe el olor que produce la lluvia al caer en los suelos secos. @RAEinforma ¿por qué no lo incluís?
>
> **RAEconsultas** En efecto, a veces se documenta con ese sentido «petricor», voz inglesa creada en 1964.

Donde informa lo que han enunciado las otras respuestas e informa que es de uso restringido pero no prohibido.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se]. Buena contribución, pero te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Échale también un vistazo a otras preguntas y respuestas (visita [answer]). Procura responder realmente a la pregunta y recuerda que el formato adecuado puede servir para hacer tu respuesta más fácil de leer y entender. No basta con poner un enlace, el contenido y la explicación deberían estar en tu post (qué pasa si la página enlazada desaparece?) Un simple enlace es un comentario, no una respuesta, ya que no explica nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias, los aplicaré en próximas contribuciones.